# "$ "giving mule expression error in regex

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to match my input field to a regex expression. But it gives mule-expression error,

> regex: `^(?:[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|100(?:\.0{2})?)$`
>
> Exception: Unable to resolve reference of $. at 1 : 1"

evaluating expression: 
Please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add "\" before $ and it will work